# How to join two table with different database using Codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to join two table with different database using codeigniter 4. I'm already declare different database by using $db1 and $db2. My problem is when i trying to join, it's show me error "Table 'db2.student' doesn't exist". But i'm try to test this by running a simple query on 'db2' without the join and result is ok.

My first project, table 'attendance' and 'student' in same database '$db1' and data showed with properly join.

On second project, i'm try to move table 'student' to db2 ($db2) and try to make join but error show me "Table 'db2.student' doesn't exist".

Database $db1 & $db2 are in same server (my localhost).

My Controller (JoinController.php)

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class JoinController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
{
    // Load the databases
    $db1 = \Config\Database::connect('db1');
    $db2 = \Config\Database::connect('db2');

    // Load the model
    $model = new \App\Models\JoinModel($db1, $db2);

    // Get the joined result from the model
    $data['result'] = $model->getJoinedData();

    // Load the view with the data
    return view('join_view', $data);
    }
 }
```

My Model (JoinModel.php)

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class JoinModel extends Model
{
    protected $db1;
    protected $db2;

    public function __construct($db1, $db2)
    {
        // Set the databases
        $this->db1 = $db1;
        $this->db2 = $db2;
    }

    public function getJoinedData()
    {
        // Perform the join
        $query = $this->db1->table('attendance as k')
                ->select('k.id, k.time_in, k.time_out, s.student_name, s.programme')
                ->join('db2.student as s', 'k.id= s.id')
                ->get();

        // Get the result
        return $query->getResult();

        // Example query to test the connection to db2
        // $query = $this->db2->table('student')->get();
        // return $query->getResult();

        // var_dump($query);
    }
}
```

My View (join_view.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Joined Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Joined Data</h1>

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <!-- Add more table headers as needed -->
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $row->id ?></td>
                <td><?= $row->student_name ?></td>
                <td><?= $row->programme ?></td>
                <!-- Add more table cells as needed -->
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm appreciate for any help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The query you provided should work if **db1** and **db2** database *schemas* exists, and **db1.attendance** and **db2.student** also exist. The query will not work if database schemas are on different servers.

***db1* and *db2* are database connections, not database schema names** in your *JoinController.php* controller (of course schema names can be the same, as the connection name)!

**Make sure *db1* and *db2* connects to the same server**, or you can use an alternative solution like below.

One connection can connect to multiple database schema, so you can join tables. You don't have to have two different connection for this purpose. The following should work.

**Controller**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\JoinModel;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class Test extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        // Load the model
        $model = model(JoinModel::class);

        // Get the joined result from the model
        $data['result'] = $model->getJoinedData();

        // Load the view with the data
        return view('join_view', $data);
    }
 }
```

**Model**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class JoinModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'attendance AS k'; // use table name here

    public function getJoinedData()
    {
        // Perform the join, now you can omit the table name
        $query = $this->select('k.id, k.time_in, k.time_out, s.student_name, s.programme')
            ->join('db2.student as s', 'k.id= s.id')
            ->get();

        // Get the result
        return $query->getResult();
    }
}
```

*Note*: now, you do not have to have a constructor.
But if you really need a *__constructor* in your model, make sure you call parent's *__constructor*, otherwise you lose all the functionality of the model. Or just simply do not extend base Model, if you don't need.

*Note*: it's a good practice if you use CodeIgniter built in factory *model* method.

**If database schemas are on different servers**, you can query data separately, then join them in PHP. Depends on SQL type, there are ***alternative solutions***. For example for MySQL, there is MySQL Federated Storage Engine or database linking for Oracle. Or you can simply migrate from one server to the other.

Comment: still error "Table 'db2.student' doesn't exist" .. my $db1 & $db2 are in same server (localhost). My first project, table 'attendance' and 'student' in same database '$db1' and data showed with properly join.

On second project, i'm try to move table 'student' to db2 ($db2) and try to make join but error show me "Table 'db2.student' doesn't exist".

Comment: Please check the **database** array option for your database connection in the _app/Config/Database.php_ config file. I guess project 1 differ from project 2.

Can you run these queries on your SQL server and show the output (for db1 an db2)?
`USE  db1;`
`SHOW TABLES LIKE 'attendance';`

Comment: Where do you use the variable $table? And you are hard coding the name of the second database. db2? I thought the purpose was to use reference variables? Not sure how this example works at all.